# Reloading SVG with JavaScript

Tags: xml, svg, load, draw, appendchild

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there some innerHTML replacement in SVG/XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723422/is-there-some-innerhtml-replacement-in-svg-xml)

I am creating a map from SVG vectors. I am getting the SVG directly from the server and i am only using the JavaScript to insert the entire bit of SVG. It does append the XML/SVG, but it does not draw it.

```
function reload(){
xmlDoc=loadXMLDoc(getViewAddress());
    // it loads an entire XML document from a Java server
map=xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("g")[0];
svgHead.appendChild(map);
}
```

Is it possible to draw SVG this way? Or do we have to draw the lines individually?

Comment: Maybe you're loading it into the wrong namespace. Does the xml have an svg namespace attribute on the root node?

Comment: We are loading the right namespace, as far as we know. The question is more, if it is possible to draw SVG by just appending it. Do you have to draw the lines individually?

Comment: It is possible  to draw SVG this way.

Comment: Can you give a code example? It would be awesome.

Comment: You need to know whether the doctype of the page that contains the JavaScript is [HTML4](http://jmvidal.cse.sc.edu/talks/canvassvg/javascriptandsvg.xml), [HTML5](http://robertnyman.com/html5/svg/svg.html), or [XHTML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg589526).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723422/is-there-some-innerhtml-replacement-in-svg-xml/9724151#9724151

Comment: Can you test variable map in console.log? What is there?