# Dynamic styling of SVG text

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

```
<svg>
    <text id="test" x="0" y="15"></text>
</svg>
```

,

```
d3.select("#test").text("aaa");
```

or

```
document.getElementById("test").textContent("aaa");
```

works fine. But I need to add style to the text. Now:

```
d3.select("#test").text('aaa <tspan style="font-weight:bold">bbb</tspan> ccc');
```

unfortunately doesn't work, because the argument is treated as a pure string. What is the best, cross-browser solution for this issue?

Comment: `d3.select("#test).html('<span>Hi</span>')` no? Well actually thats jQuery syntax but otherwise you'll need `("#test").innerHTML+=` or `("#test").element.innerHTML+=`. It depends on what `d3.select("#test")` returns

Comment: There is no '<span>' tag in '<svg>'

Comment: I mean this..: `d3.select("#test").html('aaa <tspan style="font-weight:bold">bbb</tspan> ccc');`

Comment: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#wiki-html

Comment: For example, I tried this `d3.select("#wiki-content").html("<h1>Abcd</h1>")` on this site https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections in the console, and it worked :) That means you could add inline style, too, or classes (=better)

Comment: From the link you put: "The html operator is based on the `innerHTML` property". There is no `innerHTML` property for `<svg>` elems.

Comment: SVG has appendChild & removeChild methods :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Working Solution

The main problem is that there is no `innerHTML` attribute on SVG elements and you need to create all sub nodes yourself. But you can convert your HTML string to styled `tspan`s (without) string parsing magic by creating a temporary DOM object using only this string. After that you can use d3 to create correct tspans elements.

```
var text  = d3.select("#test"), tmp = document.createElement("text");  //create tmp
tmp.innerHTML = 'aaa <tspan style="font-weight:bold">bbb</tspan> ccc'  //create HTML children (not yet an SVG!)
var nodes = Array.prototype.slice.call(tmp.childNodes)                 //create a real array from the childNodes variable
nodes.forEach( function(node) {
    text.append("tspan")
        .attr("style", node.getAttribute && node.getAttribute("style"))
        .text(node.textContent)
})
```

**Remaining Issue:** This solution does not support sub nodes in the tspans which would require to traverse the `childNodes` of the source elements, copy the `style` (and maybe other properties) from the sub nodes and `append` new sub `tspan` elements (and other maybe tags) to the corresponding parent tspans (or other tags). This will eventually result in a a sub tspan compatible parser to solve the case completely.

**Edit:** There is a more general [innerSVG shim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723422/is-there-some-innerhtml-replacement-in-svg-xml) that can also handle the sub nodes.

### Broken Solutions

There are some other solutions that should work but are currently broken. As others already pointed out, using `.html()` directly in jQuery or d3 does not work, because they rely on `innerHTML`.

```
//not working
$("#test").html(...); d3.select("#test").html(...)
```

Copy and append (similar to my working solution) via jQuery is also broken. It creates the correct DOM but the tspan is not shown (tried in Firefox and Chrome):

```
//creates correct DOM, but disables/hides the created tspan
var tmp = $("<text>")
tmp.html('aaa <tspan style="font-weight:bold">bbb</tspan> ccc')
$("#test").append( Array.prototype.slice.call(tmp[0].childNodes) )
```

According to the W3C spec, it should be possible to [mix](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/images/text/tspan01.svg) tspan's and TextNodes.

Comment: Nice. I'll accept it if there won't be anything better. But it's not perfect. Eg. it won't work if there is `<tspan>` in `<tspan>`: `aaa <tspan style="font-weight:bold">bbb<tspan style="fill:red">ddd</tspan></tspan> ccc`. And how about non jQuery solution? `.html()` in d3 doesn't work, because it is based on innerHTML property and this property doesn't exist for SVG elements.

Comment: Hey come on ;-) SO answers should not provide full solutions. But give you a hint in the right direction (esp. for such complex problems, caused by compatibility problems/missing implementations in browsers). I was tempted to add a solution for tspans in tspans (or `throw "SubNodesNotSupportedError"`), but there can be even other tags inside. In the end you will need a tspan sub-node compatible parser that either parses the source string or works on the sliced DOM elements array.

Comment: Sure, I just pointed it out. But it would be nice to see non jQuery solution. How to create a temporary element in pure JS? Anyway, thanks for your help and I'll accept your answer in few days.

Comment: There you go non jq solution and I found an innerSVG shim that you might give a try

Answer (score 0):

```
var t = d3.select("#test")
t.append("tspan").text("aaa ");
t.append("tspan").text("bbb").style("font-weight","bold");
t.append("tspan").text(" ccc");
```

Comment: This of course will work, but this is not a handy solution if I have the whole string in some variable (as in my case). (`aaa <tspan style="font-weight:bold">bbb</tspan> ccc`) I would have to write another JS function, which would use regular expressions to cut the string into parts and then implement your code. What's more, later I need to remove any contest from the `#test` and `t.text("");` wouldn't work anymore.

Answer (score -1):

```
document.getElementById("test").style.fontWeight="bold"
```

That above changes everything.

But you can try the innerHTML method:

```
document.getElementById("test").innerHTML('aaa <tspan style=\"font-weight:bold\">bbb</tspan> ccc');
```

Comment: And how it is supposed to solve the problem? It styles the WHOLE thing.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. Why it has 2 upvotes already? There is no `innerHTML` property for `<svg>` elems. Besides, `innerHTML` is not a function.

Answer (score -3):

Try this

```
d3.select("#test").html('aaa <tspan style="font-weight:bold">bbb</tspan> ccc');
```

Comment: K ill try on my pc tomorrow.