# Javascript edit SVG

Tags: javascript, svg

I want to edit a SVG file directly in JS without any framework.

Basically I have a SVG master file which should includes some children SVG.

I've retrieved the content of these children in Ajax but I'd like to insert them into a SVG tag.

For example, I've created a new tag

```
var svgInclude= document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'svg');
svgInclude.setAttribute('id', 'include_1');
svgInclude.setAttribute('height', widthVis);
svgInclude.setAttribute('width', widthVis);
svg.appendChild(svgInclude);
```

When I want to insert the XML data retrieved from this function:

```
function loadXMLDoc(url, cb) {
  var xmlhttp;
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest) xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  else xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) cb(xmlhttp.responseText);
  };
  xmlhttp.open('GET', url, true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Using:

```
loadXMLDoc(host + '/svg/frame_panto_v2.svg', function(xml) {
  svgInclude.innerSVG(xml);
});
```

It doesn't work, saying `Uncaught TypeError: Object #<SVGSVGElement> has no method 'innerSVG'`. I've also tried to use `innerHTML` but I got the same error.

**How can I 'paste' a downloaded SVG file into a SVG tag ?**

Thanks for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there some innerHTML replacement in SVG/XML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723422/is-there-some-innerhtml-replacement-in-svg-xml)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) to do this.

```
var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(stringContainingXMLSource, "image/svg+xml");
```

that will get you an SVG document and you can use doc.[documentElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.documentElement) to get the content and the [importNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.importNode) and [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild) to add it.

Comment: Thanks but I got the following error now: `Uncaught HierarchyRequestError: A Node was inserted somewhere it doesn't belong.`. I assume it's because of the SVG header. How can I solve it ?

Comment: Solved with this code: `someElement.appendChild(someElement.ownerDocument.importNode(doc.documentElement, true));`