# Safari not updating after adding to DOM

Tags: javascript, dom, svg, safari

Via Javascript I am adding a new element via innerHTML. This element is a circle element that is being used as a mask.

```
document.getElementById("maskG").innerHTML += "<circle id='" + idName +"' cx='" + x + "' cy='" + y + "' r='30' fill='url(#grad1)'/>";
```

The new element is added with an onclick function call. Once clicked somewhere on an image, the function fires creating this new element and adding it appropriately. When I test this functionality in chrome, i get the correct result(the new mask is applied to the image). However, when i run it in safari or FF it does not work correctly. It is adding it to the DOM onclick in all browsers(I know because im logging for it and see that it has been added). However, the DOM doesnt seem to be refreshing after the click in Safari and FF, but it does in Chrome.

Am I missing something big here? Is this a correct analysis of the situation? Is there another way to approach this?

html

```
<svg width="1000" height="835">

<defs>
<mask id="mask1" x="0" y="0" width="1000" height="835" >
  <defs>
            <filter id="f1" x="0" y="0">
              <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="8" />
            </filter>
            <radialGradient id="grad1" cx="50%" cy="50%" r="50%" fx="50%" fy="50%">
              <stop offset="50%" style="stop-color:rgb(0,0,0); stop-opacity:2" />
              <stop offset="75%" style="stop-color:rgb(0,0,0); stop-opacity:1" />
              <stop offset="100%" style="stop-color:rgb(0,0,0);stop-opacity:0" />
            </radialGradient>
        </defs>
  <g id="maskG">
  <rect id="rectMask" x="0" y="0" width="1000" height="835" fill="#FFFFFF"/>
  <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="30" fill="url(#grad1)" />

  </g>

</mask>
</defs>

<image onclick="addMask(event)" id="imageID" width="1000" height="835" xlink:href="RiftMapDarkSmall.png"  />

</svg>



</body>
```

script

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function addMask(event) {
            var x = event.clientX;
            var y = event.clientY;
            idName = "xCord" + x + "yCord" + y;


            //document.getElementById("maskG").innerHTML += "<circle id='" + idName +"' cx='" + x + "' cy='" + y + "' r='30' fill='url(#grad1)'/>";

            var newMask = document.createElement('circle');
            newMask.setAttribute('cx', x);
            newMask.setAttribute('cy', y);
            newMask.setAttribute('r', 30);
            newMask.setAttribute('fill', 'black');
            newMask.setAttribute('id', idName);
            document.getElementById('maskG').appendChild(newMask);




            alert(document.getElementById("maskG").innerHTML);




}



</script>
```

Comment: Try manipulating the dom directly instead of injecting html code.  Example use `document.createElement` to create your circle tag then add it to your mask.

Comment: This will work in Firefox from version 36 onwards.

Comment: Also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723422/is-there-some-innerhtml-replacement-in-svg-xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Adding the items to the `<svg>` element dynamically via `.innerHTML` is **not** supported, [only implied by the HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/embedded-content-0.html#svg)</strike>.

Dynamically adding to `<svg>` elements is a *new* feature that has not yet been implemented in all browsers.

To dynamically add/create svg items, use [createElementNS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElementNS):

```
var circle = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "circle");
```

Comment: The specification changed, Safari has not caught up yet. Firefox has but change has not made it to a release version yet.

Comment: @RobertLongson  and all, I tried just creating and adding to the <svg> by manipulating the DOM, see above for edited post with more code. When the image is clicked, it appears to be adding the mask correctly, however its not applying that mask. If I add an alert/log for that specific node element I can see that every click adds a new circle element to the mask, but it is not being applied to the mask. In other words, its adding the elements, you are jsut not seeing the effect of the added element. Not sure if some sort of refresh needs to happen or something. Thoughts?

Comment: This is already covered in Flynn's answer i.e. don't use createElement, use createElementNS

Comment: thanks @RobertLongson you are correct, sorry. I overlooked the NS.