# Dynamically Colouring graphic in Angular2

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, svg

I have an angular2 app, and in one of my components, I want to display the performance of various elements of a system. So I have the following graphic:

[image]

Which is an svg, so I had thought that I would manually tag the boxes with a `#box1`, so I could do something like`@ViewChild('box1') stage1: ElementRef;`, however, any angulr2 additions seem to stop the svg rendering.

My template currently has `<object id="img" data="assets/img/big_layout.svg" width="292" height="164"></object>` in it.

How can I create an image like this and programmatically change parts of its colour?

I thought maybe this could be drawn in divs and use css, but that would be crazy difficult to get it all to scale properly, but if there is some way to generate this, that could be an option?

## Update:

Here is a [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/mlzeRpdtYTzbia98Vn0y?p=preview) to show the rendering issues if I put any angular specific code into the svg file.

Comment: Can you reproduce in a Plunker?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer What would you like me to reproduce? I am hoping for someone to suggest an approach, as I believe mine is fundamentally flawed...

Comment: Please show us what you have tried in the form of a snippet, fiddle, plunkr etc.  Then we can see what you are doing rather than guessing.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau I have added a plunk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't get reference to element inside `<object>` via `ViewChild`

As workaround you i can offer you the following way:

view:

```
<object ... #svg (load)="load(svg.contentDocument)"></object>
```

component

```
load(svgDoc) {
  let box1 = svgDoc.getElementById("station1");
}
```

See also this in action **[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/2Ddc0ahEa0KH5wVH5UzO?p=preview)**

Comment: Do you have any idea how I might unit test this function? What actually is `svg.contentDocument`? I tried loading the svg file as a string, but that didn't work...

Comment: Its `XMLDocument`. You can use the following `let svgDoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(
   '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><circle cx="100" cy="100" r="20"/></svg>',
   'application/xml');` See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9723422/is-there-some-innerhtml-replacement-in-svg-xml