# Electron -- Loading an SVG (as markup)

Tags: node.js, svg, electron, fs

I have an Electron application that's generating an image and saving it to a temporary folder as an SVG, with a file-path like:

*/var/folders/yz/45454n1d4qqm00/temp-aa5678mpoli13554/my_image.svg*

What's the best way (if even possible) to load this SVG as markup, in a way that it can then be appended to the DOM?

I've tried using `file-system`, but it reads the image in as a **Buffer**, which is where I got stuck. Likewise, using jQuery's `$.get()` method proved a dead-end, as it considers calls to `file://` to be cross-origin (and thus denies them).

I'm attempting to load the SVG as a document element, so that I can insert it into the DOM, but still have it be fully editable via JavaScript/jQuery (so merely setting an image tag's `src` to the file-path also won't work).

Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: can't you just copy the file as text into a `<div> svg_content </div>` ? its text content is valid `<svg> ... </svg>`html. That way its editable and visible

Comment: Have you tried loading it with an `<object>` element? In that case you can manipulate it via CSS. Not sure about DOM access off the top of my head though. Otherwise innerHTML is probably an option.

Comment: I've adopted a solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9724151/2550156) for appending svg as text to dom element (see my answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loading the svg as text into DOM element can look something like this

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron')
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs')

app.once('ready', () => {
  const win = new BrowserWindow()
  win.loadURL(path.join(__dirname, 'renderer.html'))
  win.webContents.on('dom-ready', () => {
    fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, 'myimage.svg'), 'utf8', (err, data) => {
      if (err) throw err
      win.webContents.executeJavaScript(`
        var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(
          '${data}',
          'application/xml')
        var svgHolder = document.getElementById('svgtest') // is just a <div>
        svgHolder.appendChild(svgHolder.ownerDocument.importNode(doc.documentElement, true))
      `)
    })
  })
})
```

Comment: Thanks!
It turns out the part that was tripping me up about `fs.readFile` was forgetting to include an encoding type (in this case, "utf8").

Additionally, it looks like there is a difference between the browser's *DOMParser* and the *DOMParser* included in the [xmldom npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xmldom).

Once I worked through those issues, this solution worked great!